# Python: concatenate an integer array with 1 empty array

Tags: python, arrays, integer, concatenation

I have one simple one-dimensional array and an empty array in NumPy. I try to concatenate them, but I get an array in float.

```
from numpy import *
a = zeros(5,'i')
a += 1
b = []
c = hstack((a,b))
d = concatenate((a, b))
print("a",a)
print("b",b)
print("c",c)
print("d",d)
```

I got:

```
a [1 1 1 1 1]

b []

c [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

d [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

But I am looking for an integer array

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
```

How? And what is the most efficient way?

Comment: `hstack((a,b)).astype("i")` ?

Comment: Hi Nullman, thanks for your answer. It works well to me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

numpy array `dtype` by default is `float`.So, change it to `np.int32`

```
a = np.zeros(5,dtype=np.int32)
a += 1
b = np.array([],dtype=np.int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might create `b` as 0-size `np.array` of dtype `'i'` rather than list, that is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(5,'i')
a += 1
b = np.array([],'i')
c = np.hstack((a,b))
d = np.concatenate((a, b))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think numpy assumes the empty array as `float64` data type.
If you run the following

```
np.array([]).dtype
```

it returns `dtype('float64')`
so you should initilize the empty array as follows

```
 b=[]
 b=np.array(b,dtype="int32")
```

Answer (score 1):

**What is point you willing to have same array as input ?**

use *numpy.ones* to reduce computation instead of *numpy.zeros*

`

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ones(5,dtype=int) 
b = []
b = numpy.array([],dtype=int)
d = concatenate((a, b))
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works. In my case, b can be any integer array, while issue raises when it is empty. So I am looking for a way to solve this problem with minimum change of the code.